# Execute a function of a child component Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component and a parent, the parent is a form and the child is a map.
The parent has a field to write the address, when the address is written, an http request is executed that searches for the latitude and longitude and the dots are write on the map in the child component.
But currently it is only running the first time when the map is painted.
How can I execute the function that write the dots every time the http request is made?

This is my html for the parent component.

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
     .....
     <input formControlName="address" (focusout)="focusoutHandler($event)" required>
     .....
     <div class="row mt-2 mb-2" *ngIf="data != undefined">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h3>MAP</h3>
          <app-map [form]="form" [data]="data"></app-map>
        </div>
      </div>
    .....
 </form>
```

And this is my ts file

```
focusoutHandler(event){
      const address = {
        address: ${this.form.get('address').value} 
      }
       this.dataService.getData(address).subscribe(
        (resp) => this.data = resp,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    }
  }
```

And this is my ts file of my child component.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() data;
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // This is the function that I want to be executed every time the data is changed
    this.createMap(this.data);
   }  

   createMap(data){
   ...
   } 
}
```

Comment: when you debug your app, do you hit the focusoutHandler function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a **ViewChild** of my component so I can call the function when I type in the input. And so my code.

HTML file

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
     .....
     <input formControlName="address" (focusout)="focusoutHandler($event)" required>
     .....
     <div class="row mt-2 mb-2">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h3>MAP</h3>
          <app-map [form]="form" [data]="data"></app-map>
        </div>
      </div>
    .....
 </form>
```

TS File

```
@ViewChild(MapComponent) mapComponent: MapComponent;
 focusoutHandler(event){
     const address = {
        address: ${this.form.get('address').value} 
      }
      this.mapComponent.getData(address);
    }
  }
```

TS file in child component

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() data;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

   getData(address){
     this.dataService.getData(address).subscribe(
       (resp) => this.createMap(resp),
       error => console.log(error)
      );
   }
   createMap(data){
   ...
   } 
}
```